# A problem with consecutive integers and prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m,n$ be two fixed positive integers, prove that there exists $a$ such that the numbers $a, a+1, ... ,a+n-1$ all have at least $m$ different prime factors.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chinese Remainder Theorem? Can you see how to use it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson indeed, I dont know how to apply this theorem to the problem..

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok i got that thanks

Comment: Good! You can write it up, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fill the table with different primes. n primes for each row, and m for each column. Denote each prime as $ p_{i,j}$, where $i\le n, j\le m$. 
By Chinese reminder theorem 
$X+i\equiv 0 \mod p_{i,j}$, $i\le n$, $j\le m $ has solution.

Comment: What does $p_{i,j}$ mean? Needs a little exposition to be a good answer to the question. But bravo for the effort. Don't give up.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry to reply it so late, I am kind of bussy yesterday :)